# Mongo c#: Upserting is creating a new document instead

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following object

```
class Dog{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Owner {get; set;}
}
```

the following code is failing to upsert the document, instead it creates a new document and because of that I have some problems, sure, I could delete the old document before inserting this one, but that would also be 2 queries instead of 1 query.

```
var result = await
collection.FindOneAndReplaceAsync( 
     Builders<Dog>.Filter.Eq("owner","bill"), 
     updateddog, 
     new FindOneAndReplaceOptions{ 
         ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After, 
         IsUpsert = true});
```

I have read somewhere that behave like that because the C# driver serialize the `Id` field, and then it is used to match the object, but since default Id is used then the object is not matched, I tried as suggested to Ignore the Id if it is null or default, but that don't work

Comment: What about `Eq("Owner", "bill")` or even `Eq(x => x.Owner, "bill")`? Bottom line is that if it's **new** then it did not "match" anything. And the most likely reason here is the difference in case for the property names.

Comment: makes no difference at all.

Comment: I want to match 2 fields, both of those are not Id, and then update all other fields (except "Id") and to create a new object if it does not exists: Upserting a object with another based on 2 fields that are not Id.

Comment: So show a document you expect to be updating then. As already stated the rules are pretty basic. **1.** Do I match something, then  update. **2.** If I don't then insert a new document. So **new** means "not found" in all cases. Forget thinking about "Id Serialization", because that's just wrong and not the reason here. It's all about the "query" needing to actually find something. And it's clearly not matching when something new gets created.